# Elasticsearch Java API filter by string in array

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to build an Elasticsearch bool query that filters on whether an array contains a string.

For example, one of my docs:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "bar": ["foo"]
}
```

What I am trying is this:

```
String[] matchThese = Arrays.asList("foo");
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("bar", matchThese));
```

Needless to say, this does not work - I get no results.
Is there some thing I am missing?

EDIT:

I eventually solved this using a string query in case anybody has this exact problem.

```
List<String> exactMatchThese = Stream.of("foo", "spam", "eggs")
    .map(str -> "\"" + str + "\"")
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.filter(QueryBuilders
    .queryStringQuery(String.join(" OR ", exactMatchThese))
    .field("bar"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue.
Solved it using "QueryBuilders.MatchPhraseQuery"

For ex.

```
boolQueryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery(
              (ARRAY_FIELD),
              keyword_to_search
          ));
```